# Relation: Module structure on the dual and braiding?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, dual-spaces, monoidal-categories, hopf-algebras

**1. Context**

Let $H$ be a Hopf algebra over a field $\mathbb k$. Let $(V, p)$ be a finite dimensional (left) $H$-module.
We want to endow its dual vector space $V^*$ with the structure of a (left) $H$-module.
For that end define the map
$$
  p' \colon H \xrightarrow{\enspace S \enspace} H \xrightarrow{\enspace p \enspace} \operatorname{End}(V) \xrightarrow{\enspace (-){^*} \enspace} \operatorname{End}(V^*) ,
$$
where $(-)^* \colon \operatorname{End}(V) \rightarrow \operatorname{End}(V^*)$, $f \mapsto f^*$.

In a strict monoidal category we have a graphical calculus. In the following we consider a strictification of $\mathrm{vect}_{\mathbb k}$.
Then one can write down in string diagrams the definition of the above (left) $H$-action on $V^*$ as follows:

[image]

**2. Questions**

- This picture seems to show that the braiding enters in the definition of the induced (left) $H$-module structure on $V^\vee$ from the (left) $H$-module structure on $V$. Correct? How so?

Comment: Have you considered using a proof assistant like Globular? It might be helpful to link your argument to math.SE.

Comment: @Aurelio Wow, thank you. I didn't know Globular. If I find the time, I will have a look into it.

Comment: Very glad to be of help.

Comment: [Related topic](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3802638/424790)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is correct, why are you surprised by this?

By the way, notice that you don't need finite-dimensionality of $V$. Since
$$\mathsf{Hom}(H \otimes V^*,V^*) \cong \mathsf{Hom}(H \otimes V^* \otimes V, \Bbbk)$$
by the hom-tensor adjunction, you may describe the action of $H$ on $V^*$ resorting to string diagrams as the morphism uniquely determined by

[image]

(BTW: sorry, my diagrams go from top to bottom)

Comment: I was simply wondering what of Hopf algebra theory still holds in other monoidal categories than $vect_k$, i.e. what theorems are still valid for Hopf monoids.